# How to add data in one row at different columns each time you click a button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, row

I am making schedule form, using a DataGridView I want to display the schedules for that time which will be consistent for the whole week. The only thing that would change in each column is the classes assigned to it. Other than that the time remains the same.
So far, each time I click the button it would just add the data inputted into a new row on the next column.
How do I input each data in the same row with the specified column selected from the comboBox?

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgv1.Rows.Add(1);
        if (comboBox1.Text == "Monday")
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgv1.Rows[rowcount];
            row.Height = 60;

            grpclassname = textBox1.Text;
            txtinst = cmbInstructor.Text;
            //txtinst = textBox2.Text;
            txtdesc = textBox3.Text;
            txt = grpclassname + "\n" + txtinst + "\n" + txtdesc;

            dgv1.Rows[rowcount].Cells[0].Value = tp1.Value.TimeOfDay.Hours.ToString() + ":" + tp1.Value.TimeOfDay.Minutes + "-" + tp2.Value.TimeOfDay.Hours + ":" + tp2.Value.TimeOfDay.Minutes;
            dgv1.Rows[rowcount].Cells[1].Value = grpclassname + "\n" + txtinst + "\n" + txtdesc;

            rowcount++;
        }

        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Tuesday")
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgv1.Rows[rowcount];
            row.Height = 60;

            grpclassname = textBox1.Text;
            txtinst = cmbInstructor.Text;
            //txtinst = textBox2.Text;
            txtdesc = textBox3.Text;
            txt = grpclassname + "\n" + txtinst + "\n" + txtdesc;

            dgv1.Rows[rowcount].Cells[0].Value = tp1.Value.TimeOfDay.Hours.ToString() + ":" + tp1.Value.TimeOfDay.Minutes + "-" + tp2.Value.TimeOfDay.Hours + ":" + tp2.Value.TimeOfDay.Minutes;
            dgv1.Rows[rowcount].Cells[2].Value = grpclassname + "\n" + txtinst + "\n" + txtdesc;

            rowcount++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you are trying to get the selected value of a drop down list in your edit row and then add that into the next row. You need to get the control in that column and then just send it's value to whatever you are using to save back to the database. I'm not sure what cell you have it in but replace Cells[0] below with the proper cell.

```
var selectedVal = ((DropDownList)dgv1.Rows[rowcount].Cells[0].FindControl("yourControlID")).SelectedValue;
```